# Convert PDF text into outlines?

Tags: pdf, inkscape

Does anybody know a way to vectorize the text in a PDF document? That is, I want each letter to be a shape/outline, without any textual content. I'm using a Linux system, and open source or a non-Windows solution would be preferred.

The context: I'm trying to edit some old PDFs, for which I no longer have the fonts. I'd like to do it in Inkscape, but that will replace all the fonts with generic ones, and that's barely readable. I've also been converting back and forth using `pdf2ps` and `ps2pdf`, but the font info stays there. So when I load it into Inkscape, it still looks awful.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: [PDF-TEXT-To-Outlines](https://pdf-editor-free.com/PDF-TEXT-To-Outlines/) with adblocker seems to work well for one-off privacy insensitive documents.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To achieve this, you will have to:

1. Split your PDF into individual pages;
2. Convert your PDF pages into SVG;
3. Edit the pages you want
4. Reassemble the pages

This answer will omit step 3, since that's not programmable.

## Splitting the PDF

If you don't want a programmatic way to split documents, the modern way would be with using [stapler](https://github.com/hellerbarde/stapler). In your favorite shell:

```
stapler burst file.pdf
```

Would generate `{file_1.pdf,...,file_N.pdf}`, where `1...N` are the PDF pages. Stapler itself uses [PyPDF2](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2) and the code for splitting a PDF file is not that complex. The following function splits a file and saves the individual pages in the current directory. (shamelessly copying from the [commands.py](https://github.com/hellerbarde/stapler/blob/master/staplelib/commands.py#L75) file)

```py
import math
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

def split(filename):
    with open(filename) as inputfp:
        inputpdf = PdfFileReader(inputfp)

        base, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))

        # Prefix the output template with zeros so that ordering is preserved
        # (page 10 after page 09)
        output_template = ''.join([
            base,
            '_',
            '%0',
            str(math.ceil(math.log10(inputpdf.getNumPages()))),
            'd',
            ext
        ])

        for page in range(inputpdf.getNumPages()):
            outputpdf = PdfFileWriter()
            outputpdf.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(page))

            outputname = output_template % (page + 1)

            with open(outputname, 'wb') as fp:
                outputpdf.write(fp)
```

## Converting the individual pages to SVG

Now to convert the PDFs to editable files, I'd probably use [pdf2svg](https://github.com/db9052/pdf2svg/).

```
pdf2svg input.pdf output.svg
```

If we take a look at the [pdf2svg.c](https://github.com/db9052/pdf2svg/blob/master/pdf2svg.c) file, we can see that the code in principle is not that complex (assuming the input filename is in the `filename` variable and the output file name is in the `outputname` variable). A minimal working example in python follows. It requires the [pycairo](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycairo) and [pypoppler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypoppler) libraries:

```py
import os

import cairo
import poppler

def convert(inputname, outputname):
    # Convert the input file name to an URI to please poppler
    uri = 'file://' + os.path.abspath(inputname)

    pdffile = poppler.document_new_from_file(uri, None)

    # We only have one page, since we split prior to converting. Get the page
    page = pdffile.get_page(0)

    # Get the page dimensions
    width, height = page.get_size()

    # Open the SVG file to write on
    surface = cairo.SVGSurface(outputname, width, height)
    context = cairo.Context(surface)

    # Now we finally can render the PDF to SVG
    page.render_for_printing(context)
    context.show_page()
```

At this point you should have an SVG in which all text has been converted to paths, and will be able to edit with Inkscape without rendering issues.

## Combining steps 1 and 2

You can call `pdf2svg` in a for loop to do that. But you would need to know the number of pages beforehand. The code below figures the number of pages and does the conversion in a single step. It requires only pycairo and pypoppler:

```py
import os, math

import cairo
import poppler

def convert(inputname, base=None):
    '''Converts a multi-page PDF to multiple SVG files.

    :param inputname: Name of the PDF to be converted
    :param base: Base name for the SVG files (optional)
    '''
    if base is None:
        base, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(inputname))

    # Convert the input file name to an URI to please poppler
    uri = 'file://' + os.path.abspath(inputname)

    pdffile = poppler.document_new_from_file(uri, None)

    pages = pdffile.get_n_pages()

    # Prefix the output template with zeros so that ordering is preserved
    # (page 10 after page 09)
    output_template = ''.join([
        base,
        '_',
        '%0',
        str(math.ceil(math.log10(pages))),
        'd',
        '.svg'
    ])

    # Iterate over all pages
    for nthpage in range(pages):
        page = pdffile.get_page(nthpage)

        # Output file name based on template
        outputname = output_template % (nthpage + 1)

        # Get the page dimensions
        width, height = page.get_size()

        # Open the SVG file to write on
        surface = cairo.SVGSurface(outputname, width, height)
        context = cairo.Context(surface)

        # Now we finally can render the PDF to SVG
        page.render_for_printing(context)
        context.show_page()

        # Free some memory
        surface.finish()
```

## Assembling the SVGs into a single PDF

To reassemble you can use the pair inkscape / stapler to convert the files manually. But it is not hard to write code that does this. The code below uses rsvg and cairo. To convert from SVG and merge everything into a single PDF:

```py
import rsvg
import cairo

def convert_merge(inputfiles, outputname):
    # We have to create a PDF surface and inform a size. The size is
    # irrelevant, though, as we will define the sizes of each page
    # individually.
    outputsurface = cairo.PDFSurface(outputname, 1, 1)
    outputcontext = cairo.Context(outputsurface)

    for inputfile in inputfiles:
        # Open the SVG
        svg = rsvg.Handle(file=inputfile)

        # Set the size of the page itself
        outputsurface.set_size(svg.props.width, svg.props.height)

        # Draw on the PDF
        svg.render_cairo(outputcontext)

        # Finish the page and start a new one
        outputcontext.show_page()

    # Free some memory
    outputsurface.finish()
```

PS: It should be possible to use the command `pdftocairo`, but it doesn't seem to call `render_for_printing()`, which makes the output SVG maintain the font information.

Comment: this comment put me in the right track, however this was much simpler to perform for a small pdf (2 pages): open pdf in `Document viewer`, `Print to File`, Pages:1 (and so on), `Output format: SVG` (beware the Page Setup has the correct size and 0 margin) [your steps 1. and 2.] ; edit in Inskape and `save as` pdf [step 3.] ; in command prompt `pdfunite page1.pdf page2.pdf doc.pdf` [step 4.]

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid to vectorize the PDFs you would still need the original fonts (or a lot of work).

Some possibilities that come to mind:

- dump the uncompressed PDF with `pdftk` and discover what the font names are, then look for them on FontMonster or [other](http://www.1001freefonts.com/) font service.
- use some [online font recognition service](http://www.whatfontis.com/) to get a close match with your font, in order to preserve kerning (I guess kerning and alignment are what's making your text unreadable)
- try [replacing the fonts manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689487/how-to-globally-replace-font-in-a-pdf) (again `pdftk` to convert the PDF to a PDF which is editable with `sed`. This editing will **break** the PDF, but `pdftk` will then be able to recompress the damaged PDF to a useable one).

Comment: That's unfortunate. Can you explain why that is? It seems that if you print out a document, *something* knows the outlines of all the characters, so that it can be rendered correctly. So if that information is available to your favorite PDF-viewing program, why can't it be used to convert all the letters into outlines?

Comment: You are right, something does know. The fonts are, at least partially, embedded in the PDF. But getting them out is not straightforward: I would have suggested Inkscape myself.  This answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225321/converting-pdf-to-vector-image , refers to ABCpdf which I never used. You can give it a try perhaps. Failing Inkscape, looking for similar fonts seems to me the best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you really want - font substitution. You want some code/app to be able to go through the file and make appropriate changes to the embedded fonts.

This task is doable and is anywhere from easy to non-trivial. It's easy when you have a font that matches the metrics of the font in the file and the encoding used for the font is sane. You could probably do this with iText or DotPdf (the latter is not free beyond the evaluation, and is my company's product). If you modified pdf2ps, you could probably manage changing the fonts on the way through too.

If the fonts used in the file are font subsets that have creative reencoding, then you are in hell and will likely have all manner of pain doing the change.  Here's why:

PostScript was designed at a point when there was no Unicode. Adobe used a single byte for characters and whenever you rendered any string, the glyph to draw was taken from a 256 entry table called the encoding vector. If a standard encoding didn't have what you wanted, you were encouraged to make fonts on the fly based on the standard font that differed only in encoding.

When Adobe created Acrobat, they wanted to make transition from PostScript as easy as possible so that font mechanism was modeled. When the ability to embed fonts into PDFs was added, it was clear that this would bloat the files, so PDF also included the ability to have font subsets. Font subsets are made by taking an existing font and removing all the glyphs that won't be used and re-encoding it into the PDF. The may be no standard relationship between the encoding vector and the code points in the file - all those may be changed. Instead, there *may* be an embedded PostScript function /ToUnicode which will translate encoded characters to a Unicode representation.

So yeah, non-trivial.

Comment: Thanks--that may well be the best answer. Definitely non-trivial, though.

Comment: Note that the PDF format was designed to be an end-user format. Even something seemingly trivial as "copying text" was just not in the original specs--usually, you were simply told to go back to the original software and document it was created from.

Comment: Minor quibble - since I wrote the original text selection/search/copy code for Acrobat, I can tell you that it was in the spec for version 1.0

Answer (score 1):

For the folks who come after me:
The best solutions I found were to use Evince to print as SVG, or to use the pdf2svg program that's accessible via Synaptic on Mint. However, Inkscape wasn't able to cope with the resulting SVGs--it entered an infinite loop with the error message:

`File display/nr-arena-item.cpp line 323 (?): Assertion item->state & NR_ARENA_ITEM_STATE_BBOX failed`

I'm giving up this quest for now, but maybe I'll try again in a year or two. In the meantime, maybe one of these solutions will work for you.